# Two conjectures on a special type of graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

1. 

I want to analyze a special type of weighted directed graph where out degrees is equal to in degrees at each vertex.

[image]

$n \in Z$ and $n   \geq 3$ ,

Set

$x_n=\left(1,1,\dots,1\right)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$,

and set
$$
S_n:=\{A=\left(a_{ij}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} : A^T=-A, A x_n=0,|a_{ij}|\geq 1\  for\ each\  i,j \}
$$

then we can define a sequence:

$$
\gamma_n=\inf_{\left(a_{ij}\right)\in {S_n}} {max\left(\{|a_{ij}| \ : 1\leq i,j\leq n\}\right)}
$$

It is easy to prove that $\gamma_{2k+1}=1$, $\gamma_{2k}$ is a decreasing sequence.

It is also easy to prove that $\gamma_4=3$, and I can prove that $\gamma_6=2$ with similar method.I also used computer to calculate that $\gamma_8=5/3$, $\gamma_{10}=3/2$(just numeral calculations but not proof).

**Therefore, my first conjecture is the formula of  $\gamma_{2k} (k>1)$:
$$
\gamma_{2k}=\frac{k+1}{k-1}
$$**

I have found a method to construct this kind of graph, which means that:
$$
\gamma_{2k} \leq \frac{k+1}{k-1}
$$

But I cannot improve the lower bound to this formula yet.

2.
The second conjecture is more complex(vertices have a varying weight).

define function $\theta$ ( $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n$) as following:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\theta((a_i)_{1\leq i \leq n})\right)_k=
\begin{cases}
1            , & if \  a_k=max(\{a_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n} )   \cr
0, & else \cr 
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

$
Y_k \in \mathbb{R}^n
$
is a sequence.

Given a matrix $ A=\left(a_{ij}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} , A^T=-A, A x_n=0$.

If $Y_k$ satisfy that
$Y_{k+1}=Y_{k}+\theta(A Y_{k})$

**then I guess:
$$
\lim_k {\frac{Y_k}{\| Y_k \|}}=\frac{x_n}{\| x_n \|}
$$**

I have verified it with the the help of computer under many conditions.

It is easy to prove the condition $n=3$, and I think I can prove $n=4$.

In fact, with the help of computer, I guess that that the increasing vertex has a "cycle period"( for large k).With the help of this assumption,I think I can  prove the second conjecture for each finite n.

I want to know how can I find similar work.And I am not sure if the first conjecture has been proved cause it's so beautiful.